# csv reader errors when modifying the original file pointer

Tags: python, csv

I have observed an issue which has confused me, when reading in a csv file using the csv module. If in between creating the reader object and printing its rows I do something with the file pointer, print(row) prints nothing, if I comment out the file for loop then the rows are printed as expected, i.e. the data that was in the csv file

clearly accessing the file ptr is having a side effect on the reader object, but I can't understand why this would be the case?

Should the data in the reader object not be independent of the file it was read from after the call to csv.reader()?

```
import csv

num_lines = 0

with open("test.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for line in f:
        num_lines += 1

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `csv.reader()` object relies on the underlying file object maintaining a location within the file. You'll have to 'rewind' the file:

```
for line in f:
    num_lines += 1

f.seek(0)

for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Comment: ah ok - is that a standard thing, it certainly violated the 'principle of least surprise' for me, but maybe it shouldn't have?

Comment: @bph: How did you expect this to behave? You gave the reader a file to read from, but that file object does not care whom reads; if you read directly the pointer advances just the same. The `csv.reader()` object does not and should not care about where the file object is going to read next.

Comment: I assumed the reader object would create a separate copy of the data in the file, and from the point that csv.reader() was called that the reader object would be independent of the file containing the data - perhaps that is inefficient though?